# Ajax live search results not shown on my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got a simple ajax live search script that works fine when I type the keyword in my url and visit the php file. But for some reason when I type the keyword in my input field, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

My input field on products.php:

```
<input type="search" name="keyword" class="producten-icon divider" placeholder="Zoeken..." id="s_search">
```

And further down the page I got my result div:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

My ajax script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#s_search").on('keyup',function () {
            var key = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url:'includes/fetch_results.php',
                type:'GET',
                data:'keyword='+key,
                beforeSend:function () {
                    $("#results").slideUp('fast');
                },
                success:function (data) {
                    $("#results").html(data);
                    $("#results").slideDown('fast');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My fetch_results.php:

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    $conn = new Connection;
    if($_GET['keyword'] && !empty($_GET['keyword']))
    {
      //  Results names
      $results              = "SELECT `naam` FROM `producten` WHERE `naam` LIKE '%".$_GET['keyword']."%'";
      $resultscon           = $conn->query($results);
      $resultscr            = array();
      while ($resultscr[]   = $resultscon->fetch_assoc());
      $eend = @array_map('current', $resultscr);
      // echo '<pre>';
      // print_r($eend);
      // echo '</pre>';
      $resultsoverzicht .= '<div style="height:100%;border:10px solid red;">';
      foreach($eend as $result){
        $resultsoverzicht .= '
          <p>'.$result.'</p>';
      }
      $resultsoverzicht .= '</div>';
      echo $resultsoverzicht;
    };
?>
```

When I use the network inspector I don't see anything posted when typing in the input field. Which should be the case with keyup right?

Comment: i think there is some problem with ur db file  as i removed db part and it isworking

Comment: My script file works fine, when I type in `website.com/includes/fetch_results.php?keyword=a` the results with a are shown. But when I look in my network inspector no request is made to fetch_results.php when I type anything in my search box.

Comment: have you included required jquery after post rq or before ?

Comment: Yeah I add the script after my included footer, which contains jquery. If I add the script before the footer I get a $ is not defined error, so jquery is loaded.

Comment: is you id unique to the page, is your search input dinamicaly added, can you test if the keyup event triggers?#

Comment: try full url `website.com/includes/fetch_results.php`

Comment: Yes is is unique, search input is just plain html not dynamic. I'll that that right now.

Comment: The keyup function is not triggered, when I put console.log('test') inside the keyup function nothing is shown in the console. I can't see what I typed wrong though?

Comment: have you tried using complete url ?

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was having document.ready wrapped around it. No idea why that was an issue but now it works!